# S3 integration with Spree Commerce on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, spree

I know this is a topic that has been covered before but I am currently unable to get this working.  I have a vanilla local installation of the spree commerce engine (version 2.3.3) which I have deployed to Heroku with a view to getting working before embarking on any customisation.

I have followed the advice of Daniel Pritchett in a similar thread and used the configuration he suggests at https://gist.github.com/dpritchett/c86f6b617d784f943096, and so have a spree_images_paperclip.rb file looking as such:-

```
Spree.config do |config|
attachment_config = {
   s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
      secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
      bucket: ENV["AWS_DEV_BUCKET"],
    },

    s3_host_name:   's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    storage:        :s3,
    s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
    s3_protocol:    "https",
    bucket:         ENV["AWS_DEV_BUCKET"],

    styles: {
      mini:     "48x48>",
      small:    "100x100>",
      product:  "240x240>",
      large:    "600x600>"
    },

    path:          ":rails_root/public/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_url:   "/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_style: "product",
  }

  attachment_config.each do |key, value|
    Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
  end
end unless Rails.env.test?
```

All config variables are set in a separate YAML file.  This all seems to work fine locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, it crashes when I attempt to upload an image through the Spree admin console, unfortunately the generated Heroku logs are very unhelpful, just providing a 500 internal server error.

Does anyone have a good explanation as to why this is not working or alternatively where a good, up-to-date guide exists?  Spree are still yet to update their guide since removing S3 support through admin.

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Comment: I'd suggest to use new-relic monitoring to track errors.

Comment: re: "unfortunately the generated Heroku logs are very unhelpful, just providing a 500 internal server" ---- Heroku logs are not at all unhelpful, in fact they are the exact missing piece of information one would need to correctly identify your problem. Perhaps they are unhelpful to you, but keep in mind you may not know what to be looking for. Every 500 crash has either a H error, R error, or stacktrace associated with it. Also remember you often need to tail the log files as you create the crash, or else you may not see the actual trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.4, *Spree* has removed support for *paperclip* and *S3* configuration, so you have to configure the relevant gems and tools separately. In the code you provide in your question, you are still trying to assign configuration data to *Spree's* config, instead of to [Paperclip's](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3).

In config/application.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
    }
}
```

Also you have to be sure to include the `aws-sdk` gem in your Gemfile to enable Paperclip's S3 support - Spree no longer includes it for you.

(If you are using Heroku, they have [a guide specifically for configuring Paperclip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3))

Comment: The question as asked in reference to Spree 2.3